# Arduino Ethernet not visible in Router Status

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I am trying to send over my code to my Arduino Ethernet board via the Adafruit FTDI friend. I am using the 1.0.4 version of the IDE and have the following settings:

Tools -> Board -> Arduino Ethernet
Tools -> Serial Port -> COM 3

The sketch is sent over to the board without problems or errors... however I am unable to see the IP of the board when i check my "attached devices" in my routers settings menu.

Here is a snip of the code I used:

```
  byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 9, 199 };   //Manual setup only
  byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 9, 1 }; //Manual setup only
  byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 }; //Manual setup only

  // if need to change the MAC address (Very Rare)
  byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

  EthernetServer server = EthernetServer(199); //port 199

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Pins 10,11,12 & 13 are used by the ethernet shield

  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);

  //Ethernet.begin(mac);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet); //for manual setup

  server.begin();
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

}
```

Here is a screen shot of the router settings:

[image]

And this is my Arduino ethernet hookup:

[image]

What could I be missing?

Comment: I've seen some routers where the attached devices list is only a list of devices that have requested a DHCP address. Does it appear on the list / work if you use the commented out Ethernet.begin(mac) line?

Comment: Try pinging the IP you're specifying in your code. Open a command-prompt window, and  `ping <ip here>`. For example: `ping 192.168.9.199`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some routers the attached devices list only contains a list of devices that have requested a DHCP address. Try the following change to go back to using a DHCP address rather than a manual setup:

```
Ethernet.begin(mac);
//Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet); //for manual setup
```

Answer (score 0):

Most routers only show devices that have been granted a DHCP lease and since your Arduino has a static IP-address it won't show. You can see the device on your PC once you have contacted it at least once throught the ARP-table:

Here is an example ARP-table (Linux, but Windows is similar):

```
€ arp -a
? (192.168.0.170) at c8:60:00:3b:a8:7e [ether] on eth0
? (192.168.0.1) at bc:05:43:e7:36:92 [ether] on eth0
? (192.168.0.143) at 08:00:27:a6:a2:e7 [ether] on eth0
```